# Check the cumulative status of onLoadInit in a for statement

Tags: flash, image, loops, actionscript-2

In a setup like this is it possible to check the cumulative status of all `onLoadInit`?

```
for(var i:Number = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    var mcLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
    var mclListener:Object = new Object();
    mclListener.onLoadInit = function(mc:MovieClip) {
        trace(i + " is finished loading!");
    }
    mcLoader.addListener(mclListener);
    mcLoader.loadClip(some_image_path, someMovieClip);
}
```

Initially I was thinking that I could pass an array of `Boolean`'s, but I'm not really sure where to add that checkpoint, because a flash frame doesn't keep looping. Would I have to add it to an `onEnterFrame()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, a simple counter suffices.

```
var sum:Number = 0;

for(var i:Number = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    var mcLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
    var mclListener:Object = new Object();
    mclListener.onLoadInit = function(mc:MovieClip) {
        trace(i + " is finished loading!");
        sum++;
        if(sum >= limit) {
            trace("All onLoadInits have fired!");
        }
    }
    mcLoader.addListener(mclListener);
    mcLoader.loadClip(some_image_path, someMovieClip);
}
```